# Error deploy firebase function

Tags: firebase

Tengo un proyecto **Angular** y al hacer el **deploy** de mi función me da este error:

> !  functions[sendEmailConfirmation]: Deployment error.
>   Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded.
>   Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
>   Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module **'nodemailer'**

Hice npm install nodemailer y lo tengo en mis depencdencias del package.json:

```
"nodemailer": "^4.6.4",
"firebase": "^4.12.0",
"firebase-admin": "^5.12.0",
```

Mi index.js:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
```

Comment: Disculpa pero no entiendo a qué te refieres, ¿que si hice el npm install nodemailer antes del deploy?

Comment: no, si antes del deploy hicistes un npm install

Comment: Ah, pues no lo hice. ¿Para qué debía hacerlo? Lo acabo de hacer y me sale esto:

npm WARN firebase-functions@1.0.1 requires a peer of firebase-admin@~5.12.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: Me sale el mismo error de antes :(

Comment: No estoy compilando. Es la primera vez que trato con las cloud functions de firebase, no se si me habré saltado algún paso importante.... Tampoco estoy usando express.

Comment: de verdad asi es dificil ayudarte que comando estas usando para "deployar"

Comment: firebase deploy --only functions

Comment: No se si tendrá algo que ver con el error, pero en la ruta "/functions/node_modules" de mi proyecto no hay ninguna carpeta que se llame "nodemailer"

Comment: Ya me funciona. He hecho npm install nodemailer --save y luego me ha funcionado el deploy de la función. La clave estaba, al parecer, en el flag --save

Comment: He tenido bastantes problemas con firebase functions, muchas de las soluciones que he usado se reducen a volver a configurar el proyecto. Al parecer ese es tu caso, te recomiendo que vayas a la documentación oficial y configures de nuevo tu proyecto. Si hallaste una solución, por favor, comparte tú solución